# Mule:Connector for sending SMS in mule Community edition

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Is there any connector available for sending SMS in mule Community edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [twilio connector](https://www.mulesoft.com/library#!/twilio-integration-connector), as twilio [does](https://www.twilio.com/sms) provide sms services.